# Why is catching incomplete exception types by reference disallowed by the standard?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer

From C++17 standard (draft), 18.3.1:

> [...] The exception-declaration shall not denote a pointer or reference to an incomplete type [...]

What is the reasoning behind disallowing catching incomplete types by *reference*?

If a function parameter is passed by reference, the complete type is only needed if the function actually accesses the object received, but it could just happily pass on the argument to another function without knowing anything about the type.

I cannot see why this should be different with exceptions - the exception data itself might reside *anywhere* appropriate, and on the (unwinded up to the handler) stack we find a reference to. Fine. If the handler now can drag sufficient information just from the type of the exception, why should it need to be aware of the complete definition?

So what did I miss?

Answer (score 10):

```
struct Alice;
struct Bob;

int main() {
    try {
        throwAlice(); // extern
    } catch (Bob&) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

What does the following program returns? 0 or 1 or nasal demons? Well, it depends on `Alice` inheriting from `Bob`.

**To handle the exception catching mechanism, the compiler *must* have that information at compile-time. `Bob` should be a complete type.**

The reason why is explain in:

> #### [`[except.handle]/15`](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#15)
>
> The variable declared by the *exception-declaration*, of type `cv T` or `cv T&` [YSC: here, `cv T& = Bob&`], is initialized from the exception object, of type E [YSC: here, `E = Alice`], as follows:
>
> - if `T` is a base class of `E`, the variable is *copy-initialized* from the corresponding base class subobject of the exception object;
> - otherwise, the variable is *copy-initialized* from the exception object.

which confirms the compiler need to know if `Bob` inherits from `Alice` at compile-time: `Bob` must be a complete type.

Comment: Failing with my own answer - even with the `instanceof` part being technically correct, RTTI would probably be used via some pointer - which likely would be compiled as a place holder (just like calling functions with only the declaration being available) and filled not until the linker being run (i. e. conclustion "RTTI needed -> complete type needed" is wrong)... Current answer now states 'Alice' needed as complete type - but I'm still hanging in the air with "why `Bob`"...

Comment: Copy initialising a reference does not appear meaningful to me unless I interpret it as "copying the address of the exception object" (and for base classes, the address of the corresponding base object, of course). Would you agree on? For this, all I need is to know the offset of `Bob` within `Alice`, but I still don't need the entire definition of `Bob`...

Comment: I'm feeling just like standing in front of a mosaic, seeing overall image, but some minimal, but important key pieces are missing for understanding what this mosaic is trying to tell me...

Comment: You know, sometimes the Standard imposes things for no obvious reasons, like [in C++98 you couldn't use a type defined in a function to instantiate a template](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f880d2689c887a00 "demo"), which has been relaxed in C++11 so lambda are relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt)'s comment to the question (unfortuntely deleted in the meanwhile, "exception handling relying on RTTI") and essential thoughts derived from [YSC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5470596/ysc)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50735710/1312382):

Exceptions are thrown at run-time, the exception object is placed at some (in this scope unknwon, but) well defined location.

If now getting to catch the exception, we need to determine at run-time *as well*, if any of the exception handlers is a match for the exception currently thrown, i. e. some code like this:

```
try { throw e; }
catch(E1&) { /*...*/ }
catch(E2&) { /*...*/ }
catch(E3&) { /*...*/ }
```

Must result "somehwere" in code like this:

```
if(e instanceof(E1)) { /*...*/ }
else if(e instanceof(E2)) { /*...*/ }
else if(e instanceof(E3)) { /*...*/ }
```

with some appropriate `instanceof` definition (the term stolen from Java...). Such a definition now needs to compare if the RTTI of `E<x>` matches the RTTI of `e` or the one of any of `e`'s base classes; naturally, for such comparison `E<x>`'s RTTI must be available at compile-time and thus the complete definition of `E<x>`.

Side note: If now RTTI contains base classes' RTTI in some kind of *generic* list, it is not even necessary any more to know at compile-time the exact type of the exception thrown.

Comment: RTTI moste likely will be provided via address (pointer) to some RTTI-object somewhere in memory. Analogously to calls to functions only pre-declared, these pointers might be compiled as place holders only and the actual addresses filled in not until the linker runs. So the conclusion "RTTI must be available at compile-time" is not necessarily true!